# Why is my head going all Poltergeist on me

Tags: personal-practice, vipassana, meditation-effects

Lately when sitting, my head will abruptly turn at weird angles very suddenly. I'm not always able to catch it to stop it before it happens; sometimes the movements are really bizarre ( my head moving straight back, leaving me looking at the ceiling if my eyes were open).

Is this a common/known occurrence in meditation, or do I need to see a doctor?

Comment: I don't know why I was reminded of "The Exorcist". Are you trying to observe actions and slow down with mindfulness?

Comment: It may just be a lack of minduflness on my part; its almost like catching a sneeze before it happens and stopping it

Comment: You might consider looking into the possibility of a balance disorder, esp. if you have any other related symptoms (vision is a secondary input to balance). At least asking a doctor would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The experience you describe is not a common experience but meditators do get very uncommon experiences due to sudden outburst of past Karma / Snakhara. When you have stopped creating new Karma though Vipassana sometimes deeply hidden karma suddenly pops up to give results. (Many times cited by [S.N.Goenka](https://www.dhamma.org/en/about/goenka) in his lectures.)

Also if would be an idea to also see a doctor and perhaps a serious meditator too to rule out any medical condition just be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Involuntary physical movements are a symptom of kundalini awakening I believe, and may occur in other, similar contexts.

Comment: thank you for the response :) I'm not sure what Kundalini awakening is?  but in any case, this isn't so uncommon for meditators, is what you're saying?

Comment: Kundalini or hatha yoga is especially concerned with meditation involving the psychosomatic energy-body system, and is commonly associated with involuntary physical actions, verbal expressions, sound and light phenomena, etc. These yogas are post-Buddhist, but there certainly are analogues with the early Buddhist texts.

Comment: Any serious spiritual practice is not about relaxation, losing weight (I actually knew someone who decided to undertake Dzogchen to lose weight!), etc. About 10% of people who engage in such practices are likely to experience some sort of "spiritual emergency." In one case that I know of, a woman experienced a full psychotic break and required 10 years of psychiatry to resolve the issue. This is a serious commitment that can involve intense mental states for which the practitioner may not be prepared. One is after all challenging one's fundamental ontological state.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the perspective and consideration, be well.