# Head oscillations, magnetic force movement, dizzy head after Vipassana

Tags: vipassana, meditation-hindrances

I did my first Vipassana course in Feb 2016. 10 Days.
As a first timer, it went pretty well till the 7th Day.

1) On 5th, 6th and 7th day i was suffering from my head thrown back, or front, or sideways. At that that i thought i had dozed off hence the jerk. I ignored it. (I can never sleep while sitting, what i learnt in life from flights and long bus rides).

2) My forehead, third eye, used to feel strong sensations from past 1-2 yrs. It increased in vipassana and Teacher said it was normal.

3) On 7th day, I started having a feeling of light-headedness, like I was flying. I did the evening meditation very dedicatedly. I started "flying" even more, and i went ahead with it thinking it happens in meditation. It drove me away from focusing on body sensations. My focus went to forehead and head which was feeling extremely high sensations and feeling of flying.
I ceased to feel my body. There was no pain anymore due to sitting for long without moving. My head was spinning, very high sensations, and flying high and high. I went with it. This was last meditation of the day and I went to bed.

4) The sensations wouldnt stop. Even with eyes open, even if I focused at the wall, the head would spin, sensations in forehead were strong and i would "fly".
I tried to sleep, but as soon as i closed eyes, head was extremely dizzy, strong sensations, like maddening. Head was oscillating back and forth and sideways.I had to open my eyes. I sat up and rested my head against the wall.
I fell asleep very late, when the body was so damn tired that it gave up, when i went to sleep in 1 second, before the closed eyes could feel the sensations i fell asleep.
The night was spent sitting.
Next day I talked to the teacher and she said the experiences were normal. She asked me not to "fly" and focus on sensations.

5) Day 8, 9, 10: I was not able to meditate. Day 8 - I was not able to close eyes. The moment i would close, the spinning and flying sensation would start and was unbearable for me. To stop from flying and focus on sensations i had to open my eyes. Day 8 i pretty much spent with few minutes of closed eyes only. Rest, i have sat with eyes open looking here and there, or focusing on breathing with open eyes.

6) Day 8, i realized that the spinning feeling was because of an invisible magnetic field moving around me. I was feeling it like wind blowing around me. 
Passing time nothing to do, i was casually looking at my thumbs together. My palms were in shape of a ball/cup. And it was like oh my god!.. There was a ver strong magnetic field rotating between my palms!!
With this revealation, i focused on it and realized, that was what causing my head oscillate upto 135 degrees left and right, back and forth, 24 hrs, if i didnt held it with force.

7) Day 8, i decided not to meditate in evening. I sat through the sessions blankly with open eyes, after permission from teacher.
But this helped me fall asleep at night.

8) Day 9, I met the teacher again. She said, meditate 2-3 min as much as i can. The moment i start flying too much, i should move to Aanapan and focus on breath. If i still fly, i should open eyes, come back to normal, and restart again with sensations.

9) I accepted it and spent my day9 and 10 like this. My concern was, what after 10 days? Do I continue like this? Am i doing anything incorrectly?

10) after returning home, the dizzyness continued.Flying sensations continued. It has been 10 days since i have returned, but i still feel little dizzy all 24 hrs. 
Dizzyness has reduced as my meditation has come down to 1 hr per day. But not gone.
A hard rock music listener before, now even loud talking hurts my ears and head badly. But i take it as anitya and bear with it neutrally.

The first time i drove car after vipassana, i took reverse to take it out from house. The reverse movement spinned my head so badly, if there was a car behind me, i wd hv hit it.

It's difficult to focus on one thing, like a book, screen, one car ahead close to you, someone talking to you standing close,etc.

This is going on with me all the time. I am not reacting, letting it go.

11) Meditation : I try for 1 hr daily, but the same problem persists. In 3-4 mins, i start flying. Forehead has severe sensations and takes my attention away. If i dont open my eyes, i start flying with the flying feeling. Magnetic force starts running around me again.
If I continue with it, my head will oscillate again.
But I shift to Aanapan, and open my eyes. Take 2-3 mins to be normal.
Then restart.

I am a strong believer, and I am not gonna leave it being scared.
I am hear to face it, and if anything needs to be changed i am ready.

Question..
whats happening to me?
did i do anything incorrectly?
what should i do with problems in normal life?
what should i do with meditation practice?

Please help

Be happy and God bless

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When energy which is stored in lowest chakra starts rising you experience jerks. Vipassna has unleashed the stored energy.

Unfortunately your past has created lot of bottlenecks for the energy to rise upwards. There is simple technique of removing bottlenecks which Buddha taught. One needs to scan all parts of his body slowly with eyes closed. whenever on some part there is some sensation (twitching, pain etc) center your attention for sometime till the sensation subsides.

Try this technique and if it does not help go to some other expert. Do not try to force the upward movement of energy till you are pure in body, mind and heart.

Comment: Thank you, Shashank. Is your suggestion about meditation same as that taught in 10 day vipassana (which is again, Budhdha's) ? I am asking because it sounds similar. I was observing sensations in body parts when this occurred. However, I do seem to agree with your thought of energy bottleneck. It would help if you explain your technique a little more and with its name. ... Also, I practiced Reiki before. Until about day before I did Vipassana, I have practiced it.  Is there a chance that it may be related?

Comment: oh yes it is same thing...its a classic detox method taught by many masters including Gurdjeff. Energy blocks can be removed by massage, accupunture etc. But yogis didnt have tools for direct physical detox so they used pranic body for detox. Though its slow but nonetheless quite handy as no external things are required.

Comment: Dont go after names understand the principle involved. Your attention to the part increases the pranic flow and thereby blood flow. Somebody downvoted my answer for simple reason they do not want to understand, they just see whether it fits in their domain of knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

When you do meditation you stop creating new Sankhara. The implication of this is past Sankhara surfaces and gives minute results and pass away. When this happens you get positive or negative out of the ordinary experiences. Best is not to give importance to them. These experiences can stay for a long time but eventually will pass off. Do not make yourself unstable by worrying about them.

An analogy is opening a soda bottle. It initially fizzers and then settles after the gas is gone.

Also see: [Why is my head going all Poltergeist on me](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13265/why-is-my-head-going-all-poltergeist-on-me)

Answer (score 2):

*One day a young man came to our monastery asking to be a monk. He was a committed person and soon he started screaming in the night and he had other discomforts too (Loosing focus & interest). One night he was screaming and the Monks gathered to see why. The young man was talking oddly and monks understood that he is under the control of a "Pretha" (A being from a lower ralm, a bad birth caused by bad karma).
When the conversation went on the being revealed his true identity.It was his Grandfather. The being said "I can't let him reach nirvana, i will never see him again".
No matter how much Monks tried the being did not listen. But in the end the young man was relieved from that.(Monks had to chant).*

The Reason i said this was that sometimes the reasons aren't tangible.So it's better to take all precautions than being ill prepared.

The solution for this issue is...

01 - Start your meditation with this :- [**Paying Homage to Buddha**](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/15_Paying_Homage_to_Buddha.mp3)

02 - Learn this Meditation ([**Loving Kindness Meditation**](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/28_Meththaa.MP3)) and practice it (This meditation can be done on the go and does not require you to sit down). This Meditation can help you with any other realm disturbance and it will also gain good Karma too.

03 - [**Breathing Meditation**](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/18_Breathing_Meditation.MP3) can aid any other meditation. So use it before your meditation begins.

04 - If you feel any discomfort stop and give it a break. After it pass away start with this Meditation **[Budhdhaanussathi meditation](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/51_Budhdhaanussathi_meditation.mp3)**. This is Lord Buddha's values so after doing this wish no pain or discomfort to come by the power of good karma you gained from this meditation and by the power of lord buddha.

---

*My friend i must suggest that you should see a good teacher. Maybe something can be wrong with your posture, it can lead to many discomforts. Pick a position that is good for your Body Weight.*

May the triple gems bless your efforts!

---

Use this Link to learn additional things on meditation

[Dhamma Talks](http://mahamevnawa.lk/inenglish/dhamma-talks/)

---

Comment: yes, i think it's a very reasonable advice - to change the meditation method altogether, start doing samatha or metta meditation

Comment: Thank you, both of you. I do Metta at the end always, as taught by Guruji Goenka.  But yes, I agree I should also consult an expert in case there is something to be adjusted about my sitting position. As a new meditator, I used to change my position during my first 10 day vipassana and that is also when the above problem started. Thanks once again

Comment: @pritishi , You are welcome dear!  May the triple gems bless you!    Use the links i have given in the answer, those helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

all sensations will pass away. don't give attention to that sensation and by time it will fell less stronger. if u so mind about unpleasant sensation it will multiply the magnitude of the unpleasant sensation just ignore  it. tell your self anicca anicca annica impermanent you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are having classic signs and symptoms of neurological problems--Lightheadedness, dizziness, head spinning, very high sensations, flying/spinning sensations, strong  forehead sensations, palm sensations, head oscillations
feeling dizzy 24 hours, inability to focus.

THESE ARE DANGEROUS NEUROLOGICAL SIGNS/SYMPTOMS DUE TO MEDITATION.

http://kundalini-brahmajnani.blogspot.com/2016/05/dangers-in-meditation-meditation-or.html

You are going to end up in the hospital if you continue your meditation. If you want your well-being, give up all meditation/concentration/focusing practices.

Shubhamsatu = Let Good Happen To You!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same feeling of spinning from the last 5 days and I started feeling this during meditation, but from the last 5 days my head is spinning all the time. I asked my spiritual mentor, and he told me to control this. Furthermore, I have to pay attention whenever it starts happening and not to get too carried away with this spinning sensation. I have a strong feeling to control it, and it is really helping me. We have to pray to our Guru to help us in this spiritual path we are attempting to move through.

Comment: Thanks for contributing and welcome. I have edited your question so that it reads slightly easier.

Comment: Praying to the Guru to help you doesn't sound like Buddhism. It sounds like Hinduism.